# Setting AVCapturedevice.flashmode for front Camera throws "error while capturing still image" when taking still image

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

When I set the flashmode for my front camera and then call

```
let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: process)
```

I get the following error message:

> error while capturing still image: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x12eeb7200 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16800 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16800), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

If I don't set the camera's flashMode and then call:

```
let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: process)
```

The front camera takes a picture and doesn't throw the error.
Currently, this is how I set up my camera:

```
func getCameraStreamLayer() -> CALayer? {

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
    currentCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    stillImageOutput!.outputSettings = [ AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG ]

    if let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera) as AVCaptureDeviceInput{
        if captureSession!.canAddInput(input) && captureSession!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            captureSession!.addInput(input)
            captureSession!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
        }
    }

    return AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
}

func toggleFlash() {
    flash = !flash
    if flash {
        for case let (device as AVCaptureDevice) in AVCaptureDevice.devices()  {
            if device.hasFlash && device.flashAvailable {
                if device.isFlashModeSupported(.On) {
                    do {
                        try device.lockForConfiguration()
                        device.flashMode = .On
                        device.unlockForConfiguration()


                    } catch {
                        print("Something went wrong")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else {//turn off flash
    }
}


func photograph(process: (CMSampleBuffer!,NSError!)->()) {
    let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: process)

}
    func flipCamera() {
    guard let session = captureSession where session.running == true else {
        return
    }

    session.beginConfiguration()
    let currentCameraInput = session.inputs[0] as! AVCaptureDeviceInput
    session.removeInput(currentCameraInput)


    let newCamera = {
        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        for case let device as AVCaptureDevice in devices {
            if(device.position == .Front && currentCameraInput.device.position == .Back){
                return device
            }
            if(device.position == .Back && currentCameraInput.device.position == .Front){
                return device
            }
        }
        return nil
    }() as AVCaptureDevice?
    currentCamera = newCamera!
    if let newVideoInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newCamera) {
        captureSession?.addInput(newVideoInput)
    }

    captureSession?.commitConfiguration()
}
```

I'm not sure what I should do. I've tried to create a new capture session and then lock and then set the flashMode for the camera. I still get the same error.

Comment: maybe look if you get it in the main thread?

Comment: Any luck? I am having a similar problem on the iPad Pro 9.7" when trying to take a picture. When the flash does NOT fire, it get the error. If the flash DOES fire, no error and everything works as it should.